# Android app has stopped, Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, logcat

I am new to programming and I am currently learning `Android`.

When trying to test the app on my phone I get the message that says **"unfortunately, app has stopped working"**.

I read that I should see what the error is by running `LogCat` and I get a lot of error messages. Could anyone please help and tell me what the problem is?

Thank you!

```
6:39.963 10974-10974/? E/Zygote: v2
11-16 11:46:44.893 10974-10974/com.example.android.helloandroids E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.android.helloandroids, PID: 10974
                                                                                   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 179656716 byte allocation with 4182352 free bytes and 91MB until OOM
                                                                                       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
                                                                                       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
                                                                                       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2230)
                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4278)
                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4152)
                                                                                       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4002)
                                                                                       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:886)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
                                                                                       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                       at com.example.android.helloandroids.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Can you attach your code? It seems that your are using too many memory. (OutOfMemoryError)

Comment: r u running in emulator or mobile

Comment: aahhh the out of memory exception, that means u have exceeded memory size. u need to still get details of what is taking so much memory

Comment: have you added all your activity in your manifests page